# when does $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t+1)^\alpha}dt$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

The original question was to determine for which values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ does the integral $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^\alpha}dxdy$$ converge.

I managed to simplify this and even reach a partial answer:

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^\alpha}dxdy = 2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}r\frac{\sin(r^2)}{(r^2+1)^\alpha}dr = \pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t+1)^\alpha}dt$$

Fine. Let's investigate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t+1)^\alpha}dt$.

$$\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t+1)^\alpha}dt\right| \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(t+1)^\alpha}dt = \begin{cases}\infty, \text{        }\alpha \leq 1\\-\frac{1}{1-a}, \text{          }\alpha > 1\end{cases}$$

So when $\alpha > 1$ the integral converges. Great. But we don't know what happens when $\alpha \leq 1$.

I've failed to come up with more helpful comparison tests, and the integral itself is not very pleasant, I'm sure the teacher did not intend the students to actually calculate the anti-derivative (this question was from an exam)

Comment: Note that even if you can show the integral converges for $\alpha > 0$, this won't directly translate to an answer for the original problem - converting to polar coordinates only really works for $L^1$ (i.e. absolutely integrable) functions, or for nonnegative functions (so it does prove absolute convergence in the case $\alpha > 1$).

Comment: Huh. That's a problem. Yeah I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not really sure what "conditional convergence" of an integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ would even mean.  It wouldn't be at all surprising if you could come up with an example where one iterated integral diverges but the other iterated integral converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (for the main question, not the original inspiring question): Try integration by parts with $u = (1+t)^{-\alpha}$, $dv = \sin t\,dt$.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct way. I calculated the anti-derivative of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x+1}$ using Symbolab, and man, it's not nice. I don't believe the teachers intention was to actually integrate. No way.

Comment: OK, to add to the hint, then - I'm not intending to evaluate the integral exactly either, just to apply this to convert to another integral which might be easier to test...

Comment: Alright, let me have a go at this...

Comment: That's not great either. If $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$ then in our case $uv = -\frac{\cos(t)}{(1+t)^{-\alpha}}$. How would you compute this between $0$ and $\infty$?

Comment: In the case $\alpha > 0$: use squeeze theorem to compute the limit as $t \to \infty$.  For $\alpha < 0$, it gets maybe a bit more complex, though.

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha \lt 1$, $\int_0^\infty \frac{sin(t)}{(1+t)^\alpha}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{sin(t)}{(1+t)^\alpha}dt$. The terms are decreasing in magnitude.  The even $n$ terms are positive and the odd $n$ terms are negative, so the series and therefore the integral is convergent, but not absolutely convergent.

I looked at the comment about alternating series and it is valid.  Combing series terms in pairs will give absolute convergence for 
 $0\lt \alpha \le 1$. We need to collapse adjacent terms of the sum and get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}sin(t)(\frac{1}{(1+t)^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(1+t+\pi)^\alpha})$.  In the interval $[2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$, $t=2n\pi+x$, where $0\le x \le \pi$.  Therefore $\frac{1}{(1+t)^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(1+t+\pi)^\alpha}=\frac{1}{(1+t)^\alpha}(1-\frac{1}{(1+u_n)^\alpha})$, where $u_n=\frac{\pi}{1+2n\pi+x}\approx\frac{1}{2n}$, for large $n$, and $\frac{1}{(1+u_n)^\alpha}\approx 1-\frac{\alpha}{2n}$ Also $\frac{1}{(1+t^\alpha)}\approx \frac{1}{(2n\pi)^\alpha}$.  Combining these estimates and get $\frac{\alpha}{\pi^\alpha (2n)^{\alpha+1}}$ for large $n$.  Since $\alpha+1\gt 1$, the series with collapsed terms converges.

Comment: "The terms are decreasing in magnitude" - assuming also $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why the positive and negative terms mean that this summation converges? and again - decreasing in magnitude also does not mean convergence. I think.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler I had made that assumption implicitly.  The integral certainly does not converge for $\alpha \le 0$.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious that the integral diverges for $\alpha < 0$ since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ is not a necessary condition to have a convergent integral.  (Ex: $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)dx$ converges; and so does $\int_0^\infty x \sin(x^3)dx$ so it's not even necessary to have a bounded function.)

Comment: Why is it clear that it diverges for $\alpha \leq 0$? I agree for the case when $\alpha = 0$, then it's clear.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The integral is certainly not absolutely convergent for $\alpha \le 1$: $\int_{n\pi + \pi/3}^{n\pi + 2\pi/3} |f(x)|\,dx \ge \int_{n\pi + \pi/3}^{n\pi + 2\pi/3} \frac{1/2}{(1+(n+1)\pi)^{\alpha}}\,dx \ge \frac{\pi}{6} (1+(n+1)\pi)^{-\alpha}$ and the sum of the latter diverges.